# How to synchronize data between two bigquery tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are planning to write a workflow whose purpose is to migrates data on bigquery via a transfer service by performing a copy/insert from a `source_project:source_dataset.source_table_1` into a `destination_project:destination_dataset.destination_table_1`.

As far as I know, data transfer would answer the following needs :

- Create `destination_table_1` and fill it
- Update via a schedule `destination_table_1` if `source_table_1` has rows **added** to it.

What would happen if I delete some rows from `source_table_1`, or even delete the `source_table_1`? The expected behavior should be to have a perfectly synchronized data state between `source_table_1` and `destination_table_1`. Does data transfer service handle this case?

Here is what we would be implementing:

```py
    transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()
    destination_project_id = "my-destination-project"
    destination_dataset_id = "my_destination_dataset"
    source_project_id = "my-source-project"
    source_dataset_id = "my_source_dataset"
    transfer_config = bigquery_datatransfer.TransferConfig(
        destination_dataset_id=destination_dataset_id,
        display_name="Your Dataset Copy Name",
        data_source_id="cross_region_copy",
        params={
            "source_project_id": source_project_id,
            "source_dataset_id": source_dataset_id,
        },
        schedule="every 24 hours",
    )
    transfer_config = transfer_client.create_transfer_config(
        parent=transfer_client.common_project_path(destination_project_id),
        transfer_config=transfer_config,
    )
    print(f"Created transfer config: {transfer_config.name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the copy jobs are a better choice for this use case:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets

Copy jobs will perform any operation to ensure that the destination table is completely in sync with the source table:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#copy_jobs